# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable on 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that is 10 by 21 and is filled with zeros. I'm trying to go through the first column and rewrite each element according to an equation I am given. However, this equation requires calling certain elements in the array, depending on what the x and y values are. When I run this code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np


z = 10
p = 21
phi = np.zeros((p, z))

po = 1.0
for po in range(p):
    i = 0
    while i <= 20:
        a = phi[po + (po - 1), 0]
        b = 1 + ((po - 1)/(2))
        c = phi[po - (po - 1), 0]*(1 - ((po - 1)/(2)))
        d = phi[po, 0]
        e = phi[po, 0]
        phi = (1/4)*(a * b + c + d + e)
        i = i + 1
        po = po + 1
```

I get the error "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable." I don't understand why phi is not indexing properly.

I have tried to removed the 0 inside the brackets and also changing the brackets to parenthesis. I am expecting to get new values written over the zeros in the first column. I am new to Python, so I am not yet too familiar with how arrays work, so sorry in advance if my code is too simple or has more than this error.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The problem is that sometimes you get negative indeces: for example at the first cycle of for loop you are calling `a = phi[-1,0]`.</s>

The problem is that you are assigning an integer to `phi` during the first cycle of while overwritting your matrix. The second time you are accessing a value of `phi` that now is an integer and this throw an `IndexError`.

Comment: That's one of the problems, but not the one that's causing this particular error message. This code has a bunch of problems. (Also, negative indices are valid in Python, though what they do is probably not what the questioner wanted.)

Comment: You are right, in fact, reading more carefully the code, I found other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
z = 10
p = 21
phi = np.zeros((p, z))

po = 1.0
for po in range(p):
    i = 0
    while i <= 20:
        a = phi[po + (po - 1), 0]
        b = 1 + ((po - 1)/(2))
        c = phi[po - (po - 1), 0]*(1 - ((po - 1)/(2)))
        d = phi[po, 0]
        e = phi[po, 0]
        phi = (1/4)*(a * b + c + d + e)
        print("po:", po, 'phi:', phi, 'a-e:', a,b,c,d,e) # Added to show the problem.
        i = i + 1
        po = po + 1

[Out]    
po: 0 phi: 0.0 a-e: 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

phi is now a float with value 0.0.  Therefore on the second iteration:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-427fc8d0764c> in <module>()
     10     i = 0
     11     while i <= 20:
---> 12         a = phi[po + (po - 1), 0]
     13         b = 1 + ((po - 1)/(2))
     14         c = phi[po - (po - 1), 0]*(1 - ((po - 1)/(2)))

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

As some comments indicate there are several problems with the code.  e.g. 'po - (po-1)' simplifies to 1.  I'd put some tracing print statements in to debug it to return the expected results.